# Create a route that has uri-segment

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to call a function on the controller and the function I have created a route, but how to create a route that has uri-> segement ?

Example

`$route['select-item'] = 'select_item';`

Controllers

```
function select_item() {
    $item = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data = array ('get_item' => $this->Model->My_item($item));
    $this->load->view('Myview');
}
```

Views

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('Select-outlet/'.$row->item); ?>"><?php echo $row->item;?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use codeigniters wildcards on routes, You can go ahead and set your route to:

```
$route['select-item/(:any)'] = 'select_item/$1';
```

then on your controller, just do:

```
function select_item($item) {
    $data = array ('get_item' => $this->Model->My_item($item));
    $this->load->view('Myview',$data);
}
```

And the link in your view should work properly.

Comment: Or just setting [uri dashes to true](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/routes.php#L49).